# Why is the graph of $x=y^2$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$ not the same?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So if you take $x=y^2$ and get the sqrt of both sides you get $y=\sqrt{x}$ so they are the same right? But when you graph them, $y=\sqrt{x}$ only shows the positive $y$ values because you can't sqrt a negative number because no 2 same numbers multiplied together are negative and what not. And of course $x=y^2$ shows both positive and negative $y$ values. So why does this happen with this?

EDIT: My girlfriend pointed out that in $x=y^2$ the $x$ technically cannot be negative cuz if the $y^2$ will never be negative. But why do graphs show the negatives? And I forgot to show you the site where it graphs the negatives: http://www.coolmath.com/precalculus-review-calculus-intro/precalculus-algebra/09-sideways-parabolas-01

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because $x=y^2$ doesn't imply that $y=\sqrt x$.

Comment: So does x=y^2 not mean the same as y=sqrt(x) but actually mean y=+/-sqrt(x)?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that !

Comment: @gopro_2027 Similar situations occur for $x=y^3$ and $x=y^n$ in general.  You have $\sqrt[n]{x}=|y|$, but more specifically $\sqrt[n]{x}=\zeta_n^k y$ where $\zeta_n^k$ is some $n^{th}$ [root of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) raised to some integer power.  For $x=y^4$ you have $\sqrt[4]{x}\in\{y,iy,-y,-iy\}$

Comment: $y=\pm \sqrt{x}$ is a better practice to show you know there are 2 square roots.

Answer (score 4):

You have hit upon one of the differences between $\sqrt{x}$ and $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

In particular, fractional powers are *multivalued* by nature.  $4^{\frac{1}{2}}= \{2,-2\}$, however when using radicals, we are interested only in the *principal* root ($\sqrt{x}=|x^{\frac{1}{2}}|$), $\sqrt{4} = 2$.

Indeed, if you were to graph $x^{\frac{1}{2}}=y$ it will be the same as the graph for $x=y^2$.

Since $\sqrt{x}$ however outputs exactly one value for each $x$, you have that $y=\sqrt{x}$ is a function (i.e. passes the vertical line test) and will include only the positive arc.

---

It should be mentioned that the action you describe of "squarerooting" both sides is, although intuitive, technically incorrect.  $x=y^2\Rightarrow \sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y^2}\Rightarrow \sqrt{x}=|y|$ which is different than simply $y$.  When you use a squareroot to cancel out a power, you must include absolute value signs.

Comment: No it is not the case.
I graphed it on Desmos and GeoGeobra and sqrt(x) and x^(1/2) looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

A square root of $a$ is any number $b$ such that $b^2=a$. Thus, for all nonzero numbers, there are exactly two square roots (this is why there are two $y$-values for each positive $x$-value in $x=y^2$). The radical notation $\sqrt{a}$ refers to the *principal* or *positive* square root. So both $2$ and $-2$ are square roots of $4$, but $\sqrt{4}$ is the positive square root, which is $2$.

Comment: The principal square root is the nonnegative square root.

Comment: It depends on who you ask. Because $\sqrt{0}$ is not multivalued, the word "positive" or "negative" is used to define what happens to positive numbers (when restricted to the real case). There is never a need to clarify what is occurring at $0$. The same reasoning extends to discussing the complex generalization. There's certainly nothing wrong with "nonnegative," but "positive" is commonly used as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because as you said you cannot square root a negative number, but consider
 $y^2=x$ if y=-2 you have 4=x, if y=2 you have 4=x

i.e., you can have 2 but also -2.

Answer (score 0):

The graph of $x = y^2$ contains points $(x,y)$ with $y$ negative while the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ has points $(x,y)$ with $y \geq 0$. Viewed as sets of points, they do not have the same elements which are ordered pairs ,hence the graphs are different.

Comment: Thanks this helped. I just find it weird that they don't explain why something like this can make a difference in school